# Having Trouble Removing Singular Sprites from Groups

Tags: python, pygame

right now I'm trying to do two things that involve removing sprites from groups. I want to accomplish two things:

1. First, I have bullets and powerups. Once my bullet collides with my powerup, I want those specific bullets and powerups to be removed.
2. Second, if my powerups are not hit after a certain amount of time, then I want them to be removed.

Problem with Goal 1: Once of my bullets collides with a powerup, all my bullets freeze.
Problem with Goal 2: All of my powerups are removed, rather than one powerup at a time.

Here is my Bullet Class:

```
class Bullet(Image):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0, 0)):

        super().__init__(screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0, 0))

    def checkCollision(self, powerup):

        return pygame.sprite.collide_mask(self, powerup)

    def removeBullet(self, powerup):
        if self.checkCollision(powerup):
            self.kill()

    def update(self, powerup):
        self.rect.centerx += 3
        self.removeBullet(powerup)
```

Here is my PowerUp Class

```
class PowerUp(Image):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, width, height, filename,  color = (255, 0, 0)):

        super().__init__(screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0 , 0))


        _centerx = random.randint(20, 1100) # <-- local variable _centerx (don't need it in other methods)
        _centery = random.randint(20, 700) # <-- local variable _centery (don't need it in other methods)
        self.radius = 10
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(_centerx-self.radius,
                                _centery-self.radius,
                                self.radius*2, self.radius*2)

    def update(self):

        pass
```

And here is where I run everything:

```
class GameScreen(SceneBase):

    def __init__(self):
        SceneBase.__init__(self)

        self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)

        self.bullets_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.powerup_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player_paddle = classes.PlayerPaddle(screen_size, 20, 100, "naruto.png", self.bullets_group)
        self.ai_paddle = classes.AIPaddle(screen_size, 20, 100, "naruto.png")
        self.pong = classes.Pong(screen_size, 20, 20, "pokeball.png")

        self.now1 = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.now2 = pygame.time.get_ticks()


    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):
        for event in events:
            self.player_paddle.handle_event(event)

    def Update(self):
        self.player_paddle.update() 
        self.ai_paddle.update(self.pong, self.player_paddle) 
        self.pong.update(self.player_paddle, self.ai_paddle)

        for powerup in self.powerup_group:
            self.bullets_group.update(powerup)
        self.powerup_group.update()


        # if someone reaches a score of 2, then exit the game 
        if self.player_paddle.score == 2 or self.ai_paddle.score == 2:
            SceneBase.is_game_over = True 
            self.SwitchToScene(GameOverScreen())

        time_difference1 = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.now1
        time_difference2 = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.now2

        if time_difference1 >= 2000:
            self.powerup_group.add(classes.PowerUp(screen_size, 40, 40, "ramen.png"))
            self.now1 = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        for powerup in self.powerup_group:
            if time_difference2 >= 5000:
                self.powerup_group.remove(powerup)
```

if my PlayerPaddle class, if I click on a key, the bullet gets launched from it. However, the bullet is not moving towards the right (like I asked it to do in the Bullet's update function).

```
def handle_event(self, event):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.direction = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.direction = 1      
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.turnLeft()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.turnRight()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_u:
            bullet = Bullet(screen_size, 25, 25, "naruto.png", color = (255, 0 , 0))
            bullet.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx
            bullet.rect.centery = self.rect.centery 

            self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
```

Comment: every `powerup` should have own timer. Now `if time_difference2 >= 5000:` checks the same timer for all powerups so it removes all powerup in the same time.

Comment: I see class `Bullet` but I don't see code where you use `bullet` or `bullets_group` so I don't see problem with Goal1

Comment: I'm always trying to check for collision between a certain bullet and a powerup. I used collide_mask to detect for collision but right now my bullets aren't even moving.

Comment: I don't see where can be problem - I would have to run all code to see and use `print()` to find problem.

Comment: I have attached a link to my files. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MHCAjsT18rfItUdL1CkOTuHCyd7Sg-3P
Once you reach the difficulty screen, you have to press enter to play. 
I'm also not understanding why my keypressed for the two player mode doesn't work. (Player 2 WSAD)

Comment: if second player doesn't move then use `print()` to check if `handle_event` is executed, if it changes values, if update is execute, if it has changed value to draw image in new place, etc.

Comment: I started to search where do you execute `TwoPlayerScreen` and I didn't found it. You use `GameScreen` for two players but you have to use `TwoPlayerScreen`

Comment: I changed `GameScreen` into `TwoPlayerScreen` in some palces and now `WSAD` works. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OR0c4iFSRaErzP7yxLdJRsewEOdflQ49 BTW: I moved all images into subfolder and changed paths in code. BTW:  in Windows there is no difference between name `.png` and `.PNG` but on Linux they are two different names.

Comment: Hi, I still don't understand how to fix the collision between my powerup and my bullets. First, my bullets aren't moving towards the right of the screen, despite me updating it. Also, whenever the bullet collides with the ramen, both are supposed to disappear.

Comment: I didn't check this yet.

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to check the collision between the a bullet sprite and a powerup sprite in my checkCollision method of Bullet. However, right now, bullet's update does not seem to be working as it doesn't even shoot out of my player with the key press of a U. I want to eventually be able to apply this feature to both players, but also I want this to work for one player first.

Comment: as always I would start with `print()` in place where bullet should be created to see if it is created or not. If not then I would use `print()` to check all `if/else` which are used to create `Bullet` maybe one of `if/else` has wrong value and it stops to create bullet. etc.

Comment: or I would start from code which check key `U` - maybe it is never executed. Using `print()` I can check it. If it is not executed then I would go back to place which should execute function with key checking - maybe this place is never executed. Using `print()` I can check it. etc.

Comment: Bullets are created but it never moves, even though I run update on them

Comment: then use `print()` inside function which should move bullet - maybe it is never executed. If it is not executed then find place where this function is use and put `print()` to check if this place is executed. if this place - this function is not executed then go back and find where this function should be executed and use `print()` to check if it is executed. If you find place which is executed but it doesn't execute next function then use `print()` to check values in variables and in `if/else` statements - maybe one of them is incorrect.

Comment: I have fixed the movement issue. But now, I would like to work on the collision issue.

Comment: collision issue - the same schema as before - find place where it should check collisions and use `print()` to check if it is executed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Goal 2: You use the same timer for all powerups in

```
 time_difference2 = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.now2 

 ...

 if time_difference2 >= 5000:
```

so it removes all powerups in the same time.

Every powerup needs own timer inside class. I use name `kill_time` with `current_time+5000`

```
    time_difference1 = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.now1

    # ---

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    if time_difference1 >= 2000:
        powerup = classes.PowerUp(screen_size, 40, 40, "ramen.png")
        powerup.kill_time = current_time + 5000
        self.powerup_group.add(power)
        self.now1 = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # ----

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    for powerup in self.powerup_group:
        if powerup.kill_time <= current_time:
            self.powerup_group.remove(powerup)
```